# How to approch this question?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, derivatives, continuity

***Let $U=${$(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:1<x^2+y^2<4$}.Let $p,q \in U$.Show that there is a continuous map $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow U$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$ and such that $\gamma $ is differentiable on $(0,1)$.***

I don't want to know its answer.I wanted to know what approach should i adopt in order to deal with this problem?What information should i have to takle the problem?How to interpret the given data ,for e.g;What $\gamma(0) $ means here?

Comment: The primary observation is geometric view of what the problem says.

Comment: If p and q are planets and (0,0) is the sun, p can get to where q is by spiralling around the sun, changing its distance to the sun at a constant rate, and changing its  angle with respect to the X-axis at a constant rate also.

Answer (score 0):

Such a map is a parametric representation of a curve connecting the point $p$ with the point $q$. Since your region is an annulus it may happen that $p$ and $q$ cannot be connected by a segment within $U$. I suggest that you describe the data $p$, $q$ as well as your curve in terms of polar coordinates.